# Como inserir em uma tabela e após inserir em outra (com chave estrangeira)?

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Como posso fazer a um INSERT simultâneo? Quero que, após inserir os dados de uma tabela, insira na outra também!

Banco de dados: MYSQL

Script de inserção:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Cadastro de Processos</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
.loader {
 margin: 0 auto;
  border: 12px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 7px solid black;
  border-right: 7px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 7px solid black;
  border-left: 7px solid grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.center1 {
 text-align: center;
}
<!---->
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container box-mensagem-crud'>
  <?php 
  require 'conexao.php';

  $conexao = conexao::getInstance();


  $acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';

 
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
  $requerente = $_POST['requerente'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $informe = $_POST['informe'];
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  
  if ($acao == 'incluir'):
  
 

  $processos = "INSERT INTO processos(numero, assunto, requerente, status)
   VALUES(:numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";


   $stm = $conexao->prepare($processos);
   $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);   
   $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
   $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
   $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
   $retorno = $stm->execute();
   
   if ($retorno){
   
   $informes = "INSERT INTO informes(informe, data)
   VALUES (:informe, :data)";
   
   $tsm = $conexao->prepare($informes);
   $tsm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
   $tsm->bindValue(':data', $data);
   $lol = $tsm->execute();
   }
   
   if ($lol):
   
    echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Processo inserido com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado...</div> ";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
      else:
       echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Erro ao inserir processo, aguarde!</div>";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
   endif;

   echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='4;URL=listarprocessos.php'>";

   
  endif;
  
    ?>
  

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tabela Processos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Informes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo PHP, você consegue obter o ultimo valor inserido:

```
$ultimo_valor_inserido = mysql_insert_id();
```

pelo SqlServer existe o  `@@IDENTITY: o @@IDENTITY retorna o último ID inserido no banco.`

Você tambem pode dá um insert na primeira tabela e depois um `select MAX` pra pegar o ultimo ID e salvar na 2 tabela.

Comment: E eu aplicaria como isso no INSERT dos informes?

$informes = "INSERT INTO informes(informe, data, '$ultimo_valor_inserido')?
   VALUES (:informe, :data, :'$ultimo_valor_inserido)";

Comment: `//Sentença de inserção do elemento 
$ssql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome_cliente, BI, morada, email) VALUES ('xxx Nome empresa', 'B3331113', 'Rua Corona 2', 'eepe@relll.com')"; 

//inserto-o na base de dados 
if (mysql_query($ssql,$connectid)){ 

   //recebo o último id<br>
   $ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id($connectid); 
   echo $ultimo_id; 
}else{ 
   echo "A inserção não se realizou"; 
} `

Comment: não entendi como isso é aplicado na inserção da outra tabela, perdão!

Comment: você primeiro insere, depois cria uma variavel que recebe mysql_insert_id();  depois no outro insert você passa essa variavel. Dê uma pesquisada de como usar o mysql_insert_id();

Comment: você pode inserir e depois da um select max buscando o ultimo valor inserindo tambem